# How to drop table PK if I do not know its name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to drop primary key:

```
alter table mytable DROP (
 SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM information_schema.table_constraints
 where table_name='mytable' and constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY')
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [don't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views). Second, [always use the schema prefix when referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) in DDL or DML. Third, you need to use dynamic SQL, because you can't parameterize DDL that way.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable DROP CONSTRAINT ' 
  + QUOTENAME(k.name) + ';'
    FROM sys.key_constraints k
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
ON k.parent_object_id = o.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE o.name = N'mytable'
AND s.name = N'dbo';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Now, this won't necessarily work, for example if there are other tables with foreign keys referencing this primary key, you will need to seek those out and fix them first.